# How can I properly form text from particles?

Tags: particles, geometry, text-object

I'm using cycles and particles that form text. I've got every letter separated, and while the particles form the shape, it doesn't properly 'fit' the shape or cover all of the surface of the object, so it doesn't work properly for me.

I've already tried making another particle system on the same object, with more particles, but it looks weird...is there any solution to this?

Thanks in regard, I'll be waiting for a response.

Comment: Have you tried setting `Emit from` to `Volume` instead of `Vertices` or `Faces`?

Comment: What are your settings? Even better upload the .blend to http://pasteall.org/blend/

Comment: I tried already emit from volume but i think that still looks weird...or maybe too fast.
Right now my .Blend file is being uploaded :)

Comment: Unfortunately i was not able to upload the .Blend file, but i was able to put it here:

Comment: I believe pasteall.org does have a size limit. I don't see any link in your last comment.

Comment: https://www.dropbox.com/s/p2gmrovlwh654tp/blend_file.blend?dl=0

Comment: I had to upload it on Dropbox, sorry about that, i hope it works now :/

Comment: Is there a specific reason why not all the letters have a particle system?

Comment: Every letter have a particle system, at least all of the second blocks of layers, the other layer are for other scene/purpose, so i'm just using those to make the particles.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To change the shape of an object using particles, use the physics type [*Keyed*](http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Doc:2.6/Manual/Physics/Particles/Physics/Keyed).

- Create an emitting object, cube or whatever.
- Create a text object, convert it to mesh <kbd>Alt</kbd>-<kbd>C</kbd> and add another particle system.
- Create a controller (e.g. simple plane with a 3rd particle system) and add the previously created particle systems as keys.

Here with a tiny version of the cube used as *Dupli Object*.
Use a massive number of particles not just a few hundred.

[image]

Tutorials

- [Blender Keyed Particle System Tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=SbQ3MMUaxLU)
- [Blender 2.68 Tutorial - Various Text Reveals](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=IxzrkICUs1M)
- [Blender 2.6 Tutorial - Keyed Particles versus Curve Guides](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=u9_gTtscj5Y)

Comment: Thank you! it worked! :D 
A last question, can i add a curve between the two items? i tried with Curve Guide but it didnt worked...or at least i don't know how to make it work...

Comment: @beavoru For a curve guide you need to add a force field in the physics tab and set its type to curve guide. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=u9_gTtscj5Y