# I want to make the year '2020' out of coronavirus cells... how can I do it?

Tags: modeling, particles

I've already made the coronavirus cell.

[image]

There is no way that I am going to tediously move every single cell to create the shape of the numbers that'll take forever! Is there some way I could make the year '2020' 3D, turn the numbers into invisible containers and then 'pour' the cells into them? Or could I make the 3D numbers invisible and somehow make all the coronavirus cells stick to them as if they are magnets?

Ideally, I would like the coronavirus cells to look as though they have gathered together, like a swarm of bees, to create the shapes of the numbers in the year 2020. Is this doable?

It's not for an animation, it's for a still image.

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/79075 https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/52530 https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/168851 https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/21509

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do this with Text and a Particle System.

Start by adding text, and converting it to a mesh:

[image: Text1]

Extrude the mesh a bit in edit mode, then go back to Object Mode and add a Particle System Modifier.

[image: Text2]

In the particle settings, choose "Hair", and down under render, choose "object" and select your "cell" from where it says "instanced object" (I used an ico-sphere to represent your "cell").

[image: Text3]

You can change the scale/rotation/etc.. in the particle settings panel. You can also choose to show the "emitter text" or not (note that there are 2 different "show emitter" boxes - one for the viewport and one for the render).

This last step is optional - you can see that the mesh made by the conversion from text contains some ugly topology. You can "clean it up" rather easily by using a Decimate Modifier set to "planar".

[image: Text4]

Comment: Thank you so much. This is great.

Comment: @Noah Please don't add thank you as an answer, upvote the answer instead. If you feel it completely solved your problem consider marking it accepted